# Solve the equation $3^{xlog_3(11)}*11^{x^2 + 3x} = 1$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Solve the equation $3^{xlog_3(11)}*11^{x^2 + 3x} =  1$.
I figured out that $3^{log_3(11)}= 11$. But how can we apply this fact ther ? Please provide a hint.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

For real $x,$  $$3^{x\log_3{11}}=(3^{\log_311})^x$$

Now if $\log_311=y, 11=3^y$

But, $y=\log_311\implies3^{\log_311}=11$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Yes, Solved it ! Thank you very much!